# installing codemirror in react 18 version

Tags: reactjs, codemirror

installing using npm install react-codemirror2 codemirror pyodide    received errors :

how to solve this error  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvXin.png)

I am trying all such commands:

```html
    npm install --legacy-peer-deps
     
    
     - npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency npm WARN While
             
       resolving: my-editor@1.0.0 npm WARN Found: codemirror@5.65.16 npm    
       WARN node_modules/codemirror npm WARN   peer codemirror@"5.x" from   
       react-codemirror2@7.3.0    npm WARN   node_modules/react-codemirror2 
       npm WARN     react-codemirror2@"^7.3.0" from the root project    npm 
       WARN   2 more (react-codemirror2-react-17, the root project) npm WARN
       npm WARN Could not resolve dependency: npm WARN peer         
       codemirror@">=6.0.0" from react-codemirror-merge@4.21.24 npm WARN    
       node_modules/react-codemirror-merge npm WARN           
       react-codemirror-merge@"4.21.24" from the root project npm ERR! code 
       ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve npm ERR!  npm ERR! While
       resolving: next@14.0.3 npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2 npm ERR!         
       node_modules/react npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from         
       @uiw/react-codemirror@4.21.24 npm ERR!           
       node_modules/@uiw/react-codemirror npm ERR!             
       @uiw/react-codemirror@"4.21.24" from react-codemirror-merge@4.21.24  
       npm ERR!     node_modules/react-codemirror-merge npm ERR!            
       react-codemirror-merge@"4.21.24" from the root project npm ERR!      
       @uiw/react-codemirror@"4.21.24" from the root project npm ERR!   peer
       react@">=16.8.0" from react-codemirror-merge@4.21.24 npm ERR!        
       node_modules/react-codemirror-merge npm ERR!             
       react-codemirror-merge@"4.21.24" from the root project npm ERR!   5  
       more (react-codemirror2, react-codemirror2-react-17, ...) npm ERR!   
       npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer react@"^18.2.0" 
       from next@14.0.3 npm ERR! node_modules/next npm ERR!   next@"14.0.3" 
       from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: 
       react@18.2.0 npm ERR! node_modules/react npm ERR!   peer         
       react@"^18.2.0" from next@14.0.3 npm ERR!   node_modules/next npm    
       ERR!     next@"14.0.3" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Fix   
       the upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this command with
       --force or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR! npm ERR!
          - List item
```

Comment: Try with `--force` 
`npm install react-codemirror2 --force`

Answer (score 0):

So this is common for older react dependent packages, they declare react as their peer dependencies but only with these versions `"react": ">=15.5 <=17.x"`. But if you think this is not a problem for your case or the package you are trying to install will also work then install with force.

`npm install react-codemirror2 --force`

and if possible contact that package maintainer to support the latest react or your specific case by creating an issue or you can create a pr.